# ASP.NET Core 5 with Vue JS Access to XMLHttpRequest at from origin has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, cors, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-5.0

I am trying to call an API (ASP.NET Core 5) from a VUE JS app, but I am getting the CORS error in the browser.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.com/api/Authentication/login/' from origin 'http://example.org:98' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Startup.CS -

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            var logger = LogManager.LoadConfiguration(String.Concat(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "/nlog.config")).GetCurrentClassLogger();
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
            logger.Info("Benchmark Hosting Environment:" + env.EnvironmentName);
        }
```

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.ConfigureCors(Configuration);

    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

    services.AddControllers();

    services.AddMvc();

    services.ConfigureIISIntegration();

    services.ConfigureLoggerService();

    services.ConfigureAuditService();

    services.ConfigureSqlServerContext(Configuration);

    services.ConfigureRepositoryWrapper();

    services.ConfigureJWTAuthentication(Configuration);
    services.AddSession();
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseCors("AllowOrigin");
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseSession();
    app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
    {
        ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.All
    });

    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
       endpoints.MapControllers();
    });

    app.UseMvc();
}

public static void ConfigureCors(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config)
{
    services.AddCors(c =>
    {
        c.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin",
            options => options.AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .SetIsOriginAllowed(s => true)
        );
    });

    services.AddControllers();
}
```

}

VUEJS -
I am using Axios library to call the API, and I have the following setup for all API calls.

axios.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';

Answer (score 0):

You need to [Enable CORS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0) like this

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddDefaultPolicy(
            builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins("http://example.org:98");
            });
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseCors();
}
```

It is server side configuration only and the simplest way to check it is to run in browser console from your vue app

```
fetch('https://example.com/api/Authentication/login/').then((x) => console.log(x))
```

For the configuration above (two localhost apps in my case) server returns `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and request is successfull

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> Date: Thu, 08 Jul 2021 21:56:00 GMT
> Server: Kestrel
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:85

Comment: Thanks, but making these changes did not help me. Are there any changes required at UI side?

Answer (score 0):

try to use a named cors policy with this syntax

```
     public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("AllowAnyOrigins", builder =>
            {
                       builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader();
            }));

        .....
            
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            .....

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors("AllowAnyOrigins");

            app.UseAuthentication();
           app.UseAuthorization();

            ....
         }
```

You have a bug in your code. Pls notice that  app.UseCors("AllowAnyOrigins") should be placed between  app.UseRouting() and   app.UseAuthorization()

Comment: Thanks, I have made similar changes, but no luck yet. :(